# APIRTC: how to record selected streams only?

Tags: stream, recording

I am currently looking for the right syntax to record selected streams from a 1:1 conference only.

I would like to record the video of the remote client, including its audio, as well as my (local) audio.

I see from the apiRTC documentation that I can specify [options when recording](https://dev.apirtc.com/reference/Conversation.html#startRecording).

I do not understand however how to label streams (as this is needed for the options), nor where to find the labels of the streams I am interested in.

Has anyone an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

(1) The application sets labels when publishing:

```
conversation.publish(stream, {
    audioLabels: ['myAudioLabel1'],
    videoLabels: ['myVideoLabel1']
});
```

The application must set different labels for each publish if the goal is to filter some tracks. You can use the userId as part of the labels.

(2) When recording, the application mention the labels to select.

```
conversation.startRecording({
    labelEnabled: true,
    labels: ['myAudioLabel1', 'myAudioLabel2', 'myVideoLabel2']
});
```